# Is there a name for this type of sentence structure: "She looks as though she's been poured into her clothes, and forgot to say 'when'"?

Tags: sentence-patterns, syntactic-analysis, paraprosdokian

Comedians seem to use phrases that employ this type of sentence structure - is there a name for it?

Examples of Groucho Marx's one liners seem to fit this pattern — and if memory serves, Emo Philips.

- > One morning I shot an elephant in my pajamas, how he got in my pajamas, I don't know.
- > I've had a perfectly wonderful evening, but this wasn't it.

Comment: I don't get the sentence in the title, can you please explain?

Comment: @Louis: When filling a drinking vessel for someone else you might say "Tell me when." to ask the recipient to indicate how much they want. If she "forget to say 'when'" the pouring continued until she overflowed the available space. I hadn't heard it before, but I find it to be very evocative; I've seen this person.

Comment: "Some days it's just not worth chewing through the leather straps."  (Emo Philips)

Comment: One more Groucho - "I'd horse-whip you, if I could find a horse."

Comment: He has the heart of a lion, and he keeps it in a jar.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

This is called *[paraprosdokian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraprosdokian)*.

> A **paraprosdokian** (from Greek "παρα-", meaning "beyond" and "προσδοκία", meaning "expectation") is a figure of speech in which the latter part of a sentence or phrase is surprising or unexpected in a way that causes the reader or listener to reframe or reinterpret the first part. It is frequently used for humorous or dramatic effect, sometimes producing an anticlimax. For this reason, it is extremely popular among comedians and satirists.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraprosdokian)

You'll find exactly the example you mentioned on the page linked above.

Here's one of my favorite examples among the many they list:

> "I've had a perfectly wonderful evening, but this wasn't it." — Groucho Marx

Comment: Excellent answer. Wikipedia's list also includes my favorite example: _"I haven't slept for ten days, because that would be too long."_ — Mitch Hedberg

Comment: Saturday Night Live's "Jack Handy's Deep Thoughts" were uniformly of this sort, e.g., "“It takes a big man to cry, but it takes a bigger man to laugh at that man.” http://goo.gl/bScFf

Comment: Many of George Carlin's best jokes are paraprosdokian as well ("I’ve always wanted to be somebody, but I should have been more specific"); others who are known for the form are Stephen Wright ("I saw a subliminal advertising executive, but only for a second") and Mitch Hedburg ("I'm against picketing, but I don't know how to show it")

Comment: Saki had one too, "She was a good cook as cooks go, and as cooks go, she went."

Comment: [William Casselman asserts](http://www.billcasselman.com/unpub_2011/paraprosdokian_bogus_word.htm) that _paraprosdokian_ is a bogus, sloppily constructed word of recent origin and says "Educated people call these: 'sentences with surprise endings'."

Comment: @mgkrebbs: Well, clearly William Casselman has no sense of humor.

Comment: At some point, someone had to give it a name. People like to name things. I would have hoped, though, that someone could have come up with a word shorter than "paraprosdokian" for it, or at least something that rolls off the tongue a little easier.

Comment: Does this fit the pattern?  "Time flies like an arrow; fruit flies like a banana."

Comment: Casselman's definition seems wrong. "The cat stalked stealthily toward the mouse, then lay down and died" has a surprise ending, but doesn't "causes the reader or listener to reframe or reinterpret the first part". Casselman apparently tried to be clever by providing a short phrase for paraprosdokian, but failed to capture the meaning of the term.

Comment: Casselman comes off as arrogant, overreactive, and not particularly well-informed himself. His inability to engage in civil dialogue lowers my confidence in his objectivity, as does his tendency to take cheap shots: "One little Britlet has written to say there are only 2 Greek roots in the word. Oh? Para (1) + pros (2) + dok (3) + ia (4). Are they not still teaching simple addition at Whitechapel's Wanksome Hall?" Incidentally *-ia[n]* is a suffix, not a root, and *pros* is debatable: a prefix here more than a root, though it can also be a preposition.

Comment: What a vile blog entry, but at least it gave me _Stercus tauri_

Comment: One of my faves: _Polyamory is wrong! (Polyphilia is fine, and so is multiamory, but never mix your Greek and Latin roots.)_ As for Casselman's cited blog, I was surprised; I initially found his quote rather clever and funny, thinking it must have been intended as tongue-in-cheek, only to read further and find it in the middle of an apoplectic rant.  Seemed very antiparaprosdokian to me.

Comment: I have always heard these referred to as [garden path sentences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden_path_sentence).

Comment: [Bill Casselman closed his .com site on 7/2016 but you can find it archived on web.archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20160805025257/http://www.billcasselman.com/) or follow his newer stuff on https://www.wordingroom.com/home

Comment: See ["I’ve Had a Perfectly Wonderful Evening, But This Wasn’t It"](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2012/07/02/wonderful-party-not/) for the origin of the quip.