# Is there a name for this type of insult: "I am friends with many manly men. And Gary."?

Tags: phrases, single-word-requests, idioms

Is there a term or word appropriate to describe the trick of using a general term and then explicitly adding a specific term to strongly imply that the specific is not part of the general? The trick I see never uses a negation or a word like "except." It simply "adds" something at the end as a slight or insult to the thing being added:

> My classes are filled with really smart people. And John.
>
> Before you are the best and most clever and most attractive and Susan.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

TV Tropes call it "My Friends And Zoidberg" trope:

http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MyFriendsAndZoidberg

> A standard comedy trope which, at its
>   core, takes the form:
>
> "Group A ... and Bob."
>
> It is often expanded to mention two or
>   more groups:
>
> "Ladies, Gentlemen ... and Bob."
>
> In either version, Bob is already
>   expected to be among the group(s) in
>   question, but is singled out as if
>   he's not, usually at Bob's expense;
>
> This can be Played for Laughs in cases
>   where it's literally impossible for
>   Bob not to be a member of the groups
>   mentioned.
>
> It can also be used to deliver a
>   Stealth Insult: "We welcome members of
>   all professions, and lawyers." Or,
>   inverted, it can even deliver a
>   compliment: "You morons, and Bob."

Comment: poor mrhen, linked to tvtropes. say goodbye to your productivity

Comment: I accepted this as it does exactly describe the trick. If, by any chance, someone finds a one word term I will move the little checkmark over there.

Comment: @Sejanus: Which fact suggests that there's no term for it, since they just used a placeholder example. Their [Laconic page](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Laconic/MyFriendsAndZoidberg) calls it "[e]xclusion via [particular] mention".

Comment: @jhocking No kidding. I've spent three hours or more on the site on at least a few occasions. It's semi-chaotically organized and there is so much internal linking. You may well travel back in time.

Answer (score 19):

This may be another example of a *paraprosdokian*. See [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14949/what-is-this-an-example-of-she-looks-as-though-shes-been-poured-into-her-cloth/14950#14950).

Comment: I think you're right, but this is really a specific kind of paraprosdokian that deserves its own name. Thank goodness for tvtropes.

Answer (score 0):

I would call it a sentence fragment the way you have it there. "And Gary." is not a sentence. You definitely need the ellipses there:

> "I am friends with many manly men... and Gary."
>
> "My classes are filled with many smart people... and John."

In the form above it's definitely a [paraprosdokian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraprosdokian) as R

Comment: Actually, I disagree. While it most certainly _is_ a sentence fragment it serves a very specific purpose and I wouldn't write my prime example any other way.

Comment: Ellipses should almost never be used.  And certainly not here.

Answer (score 0):

This is a specific type of stealth insult.

Comment: *Stealth insult* was mentioned 13 months before in Sejanus's answer