# What is this form of humor called?

Tags: humor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a name for this type of sentence structure: “She looks as though she's been poured into her clothes, and forgot to say 'when'”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14949/is-there-a-name-for-this-type-of-sentence-structure-she-looks-as-though-shes)

I'm providing an absurd example here, but bear with me. Consider the following "joke":

> Some chick invited Tim Tebow to her senior prom which is just plain
>   ridiculous, everyone knows he won't put out.

Now, the source of the humor in this is the implicit assumption that inviting Tim Tebow to a prom is ridiculous, however the author then says that this ridiculousness is for an entirely different reason, contradicting our (the reader's) initial assumption. This is obviously but inexplicably humorous.

Is there a name for this mechanism?

Comment: Tebow *totally* puts out. *Trust* me (nudge nudge wink wink) ;)

Comment: A downvote? Really?

Comment: I think this is just another example of a [paraprosdokian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraprosdokian), for which we already have [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14949/is-there-a-name-for-this-type-of-sentence-structure-she-looks-as-though-shes).

Comment: @RegDwightΒВBẞ8 after reading the link you sent, I think you're right. But I had no way of finding that other question since I didn't know what it was called ;-)

Comment: @TravisWebb: that's perfectly all right - now your duplicate question can serve as a signpost pointing to the older question. In other words, there's nothing inherently wrong with duplicate questions, and you're not a bad person for asking one. :)

Comment: I can probably find who Tim Tebow is. Should I ask a question about this use of "put out"?

Comment: @AndrewLeach: it means "be willing to have sex". It's traditionally used about girls, not boys, which adds to the humor in this case.

Comment: @TravisWebb: What?? You don't regularly use the word _paraprosdokian_? Where did you go to school? ;^)

Comment: @J.R. Dangit I done got the wrong kind of learnings

Answer (score -3):

I believe that is called "inversion."

Unfortunately, `humor` and `inversion` are very common in a google search, so I cannot easily find a source to cite at the moment.