# What do you call sentences that are humorous alterations of quotes?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a name for this type of sentence structure: “She looks as though she's been poured into her clothes, and forgot to say 'when'”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14949/is-there-a-name-for-this-type-of-sentence-structure-she-looks-as-though-shes)

Is there a term for sentences which are an altered form of a famous quote, the alteration being a change in the second part of it for humor?

Examples:

> To err is human, to forgive is not a company policy.

> A bird in hand might sh*t on your wrist.

> People living in glass houses should use public restrooms.

> If you can keep your head when everyone around you are losing theirs, you're probably the executioner.

I remember there was a term for such sentences but cannot recall. What is it?

**EDIT**: I also remember: It's not just with famous quotes — any sentence which sounds normal at first, but has an unexpected ending to it which compels you to re-read the first part, is also classified as the same thing.

Comment: See this related question: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14949/is-there-a-name-for-this-type-of-sentence-structure-she-looks-as-though-shes

Comment: There is no such word as *∗theirs’*, as *theirs* is already a possessive personal pronoun.

Comment: @JLG thanks for the link! the word is paraprosdokian.

Comment: @tchrist corrected!