# What is a relative pronoun's referent when it follows a prepositional phrase?

Tags: relative-clauses, prepositional-phrases, relative-pronouns, attachment-ambiguity

For example:

**Stella Adler trained several generations of actors who include Marlon Brando and Robert De Niro.** Does *who* in this example refer to *actors* or *generations*?

**Stella Adler trained several generations of actors whose ranks include Marlon Brando and Robert De Niro.** Does *who* in this example refer to *actors* or *generations*?

Comment: In both sentences, it's ambiguous -- the relative can refer to either prior noun phrase. This is what is known in the trade as an "[attachment ambiguity](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/147222/15299)" -- it tends to happen at the end of a sentence, when there are a lot of qualifications, one after another.

Comment: However, the ambiguity is rather resolved in the first case by the choice of relative _who_ which refers only to people (or, at least, sentient beings). In the second case, _whose_ is not restricted to people, so it might attach to either.

Comment: Ahh good point! @ColinFine

Comment: @ColinFine When 'generations' means 'generations of people', I think 'generations' itself can be the antecedent of the relative word _who_.

Comment: [Strongly related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/590219/2085).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, the question is which word is the *head* of the NP which "who" refers to.

In this case it's easy to resolve any ambiguity. You can train actors but you can't train a generation. The only way to understand the first sentence entails treating "several generations of" as a quantifier. As such, "generations" can't be that head. This implies that that head must be "actors".

Compare:

Stella Adler trained a large number of actors who include Marlon Brando and Robert De Niro.

In this variant, the head of the NP referred to be "who" can't be "number".

Comment: This is an interesting take on analyzing the sentence. I haven't read much about quantifiers yet. Are there any sources that you can share so that I can up on them? I'm not 100% convinced yet that "generations" is not the head of the sentence.

Comment: Determining the head of an NP is not really based on semantics, but on what linguistic theory you follow. Also, I think you can "train a generation". _Stella Adler trained several generations._ makes sense to me as a stand-alone sentence.

Answer (score 0):

The referent of a pronoun is a semantic unit and need not map one-to-one on a given word. In this case *who* is coreferent with the noun phrase (NP) *several generations of actors.*