# How would you describe the semantic phenomenon that allows this joke?

Tags: grammar, past-tense

Groucho Marx had a joke that's long been a favorite of mine:

> I've had a wonderful time; this wasn't it.

I assume he's using the present perfect to say *I've had a wonderful time.*

But, when he tacks on *this wasn't it* does it change to past perfect?

Or was it past perfect all along because of the *have had* construction?

Comment: The word 'had' is reanalyzed from a tense/aspect helper verb to the content verb 'to be in possession of'.

Comment: @Mitch Thanks. Can you make that an answer and expand upon it slightly so I can accept it!  It's really helpful!

Comment: @Mitch I always loved the joke, but I wanted to be able to try and translate it (if possible).  Knowing exactly how to describe it helps me to determine if I can. Thanks again!

Comment: I think you're referring to "tense", not "case". (Case is usually used for nouns; examples are subject, object, possessive...)

Comment: Nah, it's not a tense, either. Perfect is a construction using the auxiliary verb _have_ followed by the perfect passive participle of the next verb in the verb chain. English only has two tenses, past and perfect. This perfect construction is in the present tense (_have had_).

Comment: @JohnLawler meant to type *past and present*, of course.

Comment: Sorry, yes. Thanks. I have often thought that there are entirely too many grammatical terms beginning with P and Pr.

Comment: @Mitch It's not really possession. It's more like the sense of _had_ in "I've had hamburgers before."

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14949/is-there-a-name-for-this-type-of-sentence-structure-she-looks-as-though-shes/14950#14950

Answer (score 24, accepted):

(btw, there should be a full stop after *wonderful time*; otherwise it's a comma splice.)

Here's the way it works. There are [four senses of the English Perfect Construction](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/63263/15299).
Normally the fixed phrase *I've had a wonderful time* would be interpreted in its **Universal** sense:

> "used to indicate that a state of affairs prevailed throughout some interval stretching
>      from the past into the present: *I've known Max since 1960*."

This means that from the start of whatever is going on (normally a party or other social event), the speaker has enjoyed themself, and thus this is a stereotypical leavetaking compliment to the host.

However, the next clause -- *This wasn't it* -- forces the Perfect into its **Existential** sense:

> " used to indicate the existence of past events: *I have read the book five times.*

Therefore the implied compliment from the Universal sense is withdrawn, and the host is insulted.

Comment: Oh, and it's not "case". English has no case. It's a matter of varying the interpretation of the English perfect construction. Does that help?

Comment: '(btw, there should be a full stop after wonderful time; otherwise it's a comma splice.)' It should have been a semicolon, but Zeppo didn't know how to spell it. (Actually, I think Groucho inserted a 'but'.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You're correct about the semicolon.  I've added it.  And, I can't remember if he said but . . . I believe not though, which adds to the humor.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thanks!  I've admitted that I'm often hopeless when it comes to properly naming parts of speech and grammatical constructs.  Fortunately, I typically use them correctly regardless of my ability to name them.

Comment: +1, good answer. While this is not a case, English arguably has a subjective-objective case distinction in pronouns. As to your term *existential*, one might also call this use of the present perfect *indefinite*, referring to an indefinite point of time in the past, as opposed to the simple past, which normally refers to a more specific point.

Comment: @Cerberus: There are four (maybe 5) words in English that can be said to be in the objective case. There are far more words in English that can be said to be in the locative case, but we don't say that English has a locative case. That's because cases are sposta **simplify** things. Oh, and the terms _universal_ and _existential_ aren't mine; they're McCawley's, and they're standard.

Comment: @JohnLawler I have to admit, I LOVE your usage of words like *sposta* on a site like this!  I makes me laugh for at least a minute each time I see it.

Comment: Write like you talk. That's the only way to do it.

Comment: ... You talk in semicolons?

Comment: I talk with intonation, and that includes full stops like semicolons.

Comment: My wife says she has decided to learn to speak Spanish. I'm dying to see her handle those upside-down question marks.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I do talk in semi-colons. But, I can't do it too frequently. It's a terrible strain on the gums and lips!

Comment: @JohnLawler your answer is excellent except for the categorisation of the phrase to be normally interpreted in the "universal" sense. If I tell a host "I've had a wonderful time", isn't the assumed contextual framework subjective to the current event?

Comment: The assumed contextual framework normally would be, yes. That's why it works as a fixed phrase when leaving a party. But the second clause makes that impossible, so the existential (which does not assume present relevance) is forced. That's a reversal, from a compliment to an insult, which is the point of the joke. And I don't want to analyze the joke any more.

Comment: @JohnLawler: The issue with *existential* is that it is also used for the use of *be* in the sense of *there was a large house*, because that means "there existed a large house". The connection between existence and the—as I call it—indefinite present perfect is weaker. For one thing, it applies also to states of affairs that do not express existence any more specifically than the average situation. *Indefinite* neatly describes its use for a situation not situated at a specific point in the past. It is also the word *I* have seen used to describe it.

Comment: ... Jean-Paul should have patented the term.

Comment: These comments remind me of this video I saw the other day: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6bpIbdZhrzA&feature=kp -- talk like you write (or rather read)

Comment: "(btw, there should be a full stop after wonderful time; otherwise it's a comma splice.)" Why isn't the SEMIcolon enough to prevent a comma splice?

Comment: As I mentioned in one comment or another above, a semicolon **is** a full stop, phonologically. They're not necessary in speech, but they're handy in writing because they allow us to join sentences visually that are semantically and pragmatically connected in the discourse; there is more to come; it will get better, [as Lewis Thomas puts it](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/punctuation.html).

Answer (score 8):

> I've had a wonderful time; this wasn't it.

The joke works on the cancellation of a previously created implicature.

The first clause,

- *I've had a wonderful time;*

implies that the speaker (the "I") has *just* had a wonderful time -- that the most recent event was that wonderful time. (But this is not an entailment, and so could be explicitly cancelled, and if cancelled, it is usually cancelled almost immediately in the next clause or sentence *by native English speakers*.)

The next clause,

- *this wasn't it.*

cancels that previous implicature. Thus, the "joke".

I've noticed that many EFL speakers can't get the handle on this sort of creation and canceling of implicatures. (Aside: Especially the ones who think they know English grammar better than the native speakers, and they argue and argue, not understanding that what they are saying ain't quite what they think it is.)

EDITED to add more info:

One of the main differences between the *present-perfect* construction and the *past-perfect* is that the present-perfect explicitly includes the present time-sphere. Both types of perfect construction include the past time-sphere.

In the OP's example *"I've had a wonderful time; this wasn't it"*, the verb construction of the first main clause has not changed -- it is still a present-perfect construction, which is used to talk about the past but with the understanding that the present is also important.

If the present wasn't to be included (present == this current social event), then the speaker would normally use the past-perfect ("I had had a wonderful time") which would explicitly omit that current/recent social event, but that would sound weird for this social situation, where it is assumed that a guest is thanking the host for a wonderful time at the host's event. And that assumption of "thanks" is needed for the joke to work.

If a guest wanted to thank the host, then the simple past would often work, *"I had a wonderful time"*, as it could refer to the very recent past which could refer to the just concluded social event. But then the joke probably wouldn't work as well,

- *I had a wonderful time; this wasn't it."*

For the original joke with the present-perfect is explicitly including the present time-sphere, which strongly pulls in the implicature that the speaker is talking about the current social event as being that "a wonderful time".

The present-perfect has various uses, and one of them is to talk about a past situation that is very close to "now". Often, that situation is the present situation or a very recent situation. The joke relies on that common usage.

Comment: ......Upstarts!

Comment: I understand the premise of the joke. I'm trying to figure out what grammatical terms shift in between the clauses in order to subvert the reader.

Comment: @DavidM As I said in my post, it was that the reader assumed an implicature which was then cancelled. The verb construction of the first main clause has not changed -- it is still a present-perfect construction, which is used to talk about the past but with the understanding that the present is also important. If the present wasn't involved (present == this current social event), then the speaker would normally use the past-perfect ("I had had a wonderful time") which would explicitly omit that current/recent social event. If you think it would be helpful, I could add this info to my post.

Comment: Yes. The fact that the joke remains in the present perfect is helpful. I was thinking of trying to translate it, but couldn't quite isolate the proper tense to do so.

Comment: @F.E. +1 for a good explanation. Maybe I'm being a bit thick here, but I think that this was rather straightforward. I don't seem to get what possibly could have stumped the OP.

Answer (score 3):

"Brevity is the soul of wit," or so they say. If I suck out the brevity from Marx's witticism and add a bunch of words, it would look as follows:

> "I've had a wonderful time in the past at gatherings similar to this, but this particular gathering did not qualify as a wonderful time."

The witticism is gone, obviously, but both "wonderful times" are in the past (viz., the near past and the not so near past).

Also, as Mitch, above, points out, the word *had* is used somewhat metaphorically to mean "[I have] experienced" or "[I have] been in the possession of" a good time. Consequently, the host of the party thinks initially to himself or herself,

> "Oh, my guest is saying he has just had a good time at my gathering."

When he hears "this wasn't it," however, he then understands the insult, and thinks to himself,

> "Oh, my guest has had a good time at a party other than mine, but he did not have a good time at my party."

They didn't call Groucho, *Grouch*-o, for nothing!

Comment: Perhaps it was the party of the first part.

Comment: Indeed! Bringing Groucho's zinger up to date, you might end up with, "I've partied hearty, but not here!"

Comment: This is Groucho's signature move: use a word or phrase that leads everyone into thinking one thing, and then deliver the surprise punchline. _One morning I shot an elephant in my pajamas. How he got in my pajamas I'll never know._ Translating some of these zingers could be tough.

Comment: Even pyjamas doesn't sound right.

Answer (score 0):

The joke works, if it works at all, because speaker and listener understand different things by *I've had a wonderful time*. The listener assumes it relates to some event at which the listener has been the host. The speaker, however, has in mind some other event. There is no change in the function of the verb phrase *‘ve had*.

Comment: I think strictly speaking your last line isn't really true. Or at least, it might depend on whether you mean the *grammatical* function (i.e. - it's always "present perfect"), as opposed to the *semantic* function (it may refer to the immediate past as part of the "present context", or some much earlier time).

Comment: I understand the joke's meaning.  (After all, it's a favorite of mine.)  I just was wondering if there was a name for the grammatical sense of the shift in meaning.  I believe that @JohhLawler has it correctly above.

Comment: @FumbleFingers. Yes, I think I meant the grammatical function. I had in mind Mitch's answer, which I didn't think quite was quite right. John has explained it fully. Anyway, it's a pretty feeble joke.

Comment: @Barrie: Yeah - I *definitely* didn't think Mitch's comment was right there (after all, it's exactly the same *present perfect* however you interpret it). Truth to tell, I upvoted your answer on the strength of your last line *before* reading John's answer - at which point I nipped back to yours, cancelled the upvote, and posted my comment. John's answer has now justly floated to the top of the list, and I feel somewhat enlightened by his *Universal/Existential* distinction. And I only think it's a feeble joke because I've heard it so many times - it was certainly funny to me as a teenager!

Answer (score 0):

The normal sense of the sentence

```
I've had a wonderful time.
```

when spoken to the host is to refer to the current occasion. However, `had` can also be used in a sentence like:

```
I've had a wonderful steak.
```

In this case, it's referring to a past event.

The ambiguity is normally resolved based on social norms. The joke occurs when Groucho uses his clarification "and this wasn't it" to switch from the first sense to the second.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was considering translating this joke for an Italian friend of mine.  Hence, I was looking for the semantic sense of the joke.